# Как проверить наличие установленного Python на компьютере с помощью Java?

Tags: java, javafx

Пишу программу,которая запускает .py скрипт в фоне через GUI на Java.
Нужно проверить наличие Python на компьютере и если его нет,то не запускать программу.
Каким образом это можно сделать?

Comment: Как вариант это выполнить команду для `cmd` из джавы. Для примера просто вывести что-то в консоль на питоне.

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать выполнить команду и отследить вывод

```
button.setOnAction(event -> {
    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process process = runtime.exec("python command");
    process.getOutputStream()  
});
```